# Java Error When attempting to use the return from a method as an item in an if statement

Tags: java

I keep getting the following errors:
Cannot find symbol
Variable find

cannot find symbol
method getdata(int)

I am sure I am making this way more difficult than it is, but I am not sure how make this work so that the return from searching through the array, can be seen and evaluated by the if statement.

```
                   //assigns manager identification 
                    manID = keyboard.nextInt();

        //Fibonacci binary array for passwords
        int[] passWArray = {00000000,00000001,00000001,00000010,00000011,00000101,00001000,00001101};

        //item = find.getdata(manID);

        if (getdata(manID) != -1) 
        {
        //Do work here
        dblPayRate = 10.85;
        dblGrossPay =  (intHours * dblPayRate) + (15.00);
        dblTaxes = dblGrossPay * 0.19;
        dblGrossPay -= dblTaxes;

        //Print information to user
        System.out.print("\n\n$" + df2.format(dblTaxes) + 
        " was withheld from this paycheck in taxes after working "+ intHours + " hours.\n\n");
        System.out.print("The amount \"Employer Here\" owes you is $" + df2.format(dblGrossPay) + "\n");
        }
        else
        {
        // Dialog box for incorrect password
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Entry! Contact the BOFH!");
        //exits program (Note: needed for any JOptionPane programs)
        System.exit(0); 
        }
    }// end of long if statement for >50 hours
}//end of main method

 public int find(int[] passWArray, int manID) 
{
    //search for manID in passWArray array
    for (int index = 0; index < passWArray.length; index++) 

        if ( passWArray[index] == manID )

            return manID;
    //-1 indicates the value was not found      
    return -1;

}// end of find method
```

Comment: Where is your getdata method defined?

Comment: You're missing the beginning part of your code, so it's hard to know what's really wrong, but your comment about "end of long if statement" is on a line that is *not* the end of the if statement shown. Is that talking about some other if statement? Also, as an aside, are you aware that the values in passWArray are octal, not binary (or decimal)?

Comment: If you paid more attention to code style, your code would be easier to read ... and spot syntax errors in.

Comment: I'm taking from this, that you have a veeeery long `if` statement in your first method: just as a general note, you better break a long evaluation routine like that into various steps handled by class methods -- or outsource them to other classes (this is called, **modulization**, or **modular-programming-style**). Writing modular code might seem more work at first, but it will be easier to debug, maintain and reuse. It's really one of the boons of object oriented programming, in contrast to imperative programming.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if (getdata(manID) != -1)
```

into

```
if (find(passWArray , manID) != -1)
```

BTW those numbers don't magically become binary because they only contain 0's and 1's. Here's a hint:

```
int thirteen = Integer.parseInt("00001101", 2)
```

EDIT: in response to your next error

For now make the method static:

```
public static int find(int[] passWArray, int manID)
```

Eventually you might want to think about your 'Object-Oriented design' and just use the main() method as an entry point. Within main you create an instance of a class and let it do its work. In this way you can use the powers of O-O like encapsulation and inheritance and don't have to make everything static.

EDIT2: Afterthought

Your program seems to have the following 'actions':

- user interaction
- authentication
- calculation

And there seem to be the following 'things' in your domain:

- user
- password
- keyboard
- display (command line and screen)
- calculation

A good rule of thumb for an O-O design is to convert some of the 'things' and 'actions' already present in your domain into classes. A good class has a single responsibility and shares as little as possible of its data and methods with other classes (this is called information hiding).

Here's a class diagram that comes to mind:

- User (represents a user, contains a single field 'password')
- Authenticator (authenticates a user, contains the list of allowed passwords)
- Console (all user interaction, either use System.out/in or Swing, but don't mix them)
- Calculator (it calculates shit)

Comment: Thanks for the if statement help, and yeah I wanted the array to be those sets of numbers, not parsed. Thanks though.

Comment: non-static method find(int[],int) cannot be referenced from a static context.

Comment: @Peter Are you calling these methods from the main? You need a reference to an object to call non-static methods. In this case you can just make find static.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to tweak it a bit and solve. Fixed the long list of notation taboos as well. I will post better looking code next time before I ask a question. I think the lack of convention was a problem in both my understanding what was wrong, and posters from reading it.